# How to show that given two acute angles, the sine ratio of the greater angle is greater than the sine ratio of lesser angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, triangles

How do I show that for angles $\theta ,\psi \in [0^°,90^°$], if $\theta > \psi$, then $\sin \theta > \sin \psi$?

I thought of proving this by creating two right triangles with the same hypotenuse length $h$, one having an acute angle of $\theta$ and another right triangle having one of its acute angle as $\psi$. I denote the side opposite to $\theta$ and $\psi$ as $p$ and $q$, respectively.

[[image: Two right triangles with the same hypotenuse, one triangle with an acute angle of <span class=]$\theta$ and another triangle with its acute angle being $\psi$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071vy.jpg)

Then by the greater side is opposite to greater angle in a triangle theorem:
$$p>q$$

$$\frac{p}{h}> \frac{q}{h}$$

Therefore, $\sin \theta = \frac{p}{h}> \frac{q}{h} = \sin \psi$. However, I then realize that the 'greater side is opposite the greater angle' should be applied within a triangle. I also think that maybe I shouldn't assume that both right triangles have the same hypotenuse length. How would I modify this proof so that it is correct? Or is it that I'll have to find a completely different approach of proving this? I'm still new to trigonometry so I hope that the proofs given won't use any complicated theorems. Thank you.

Comment: *"I also think that maybe I shouldn't assume that both right triangles have the same hypotenuse length."* << Why not? You're the one constructing the triangles. You can choose both hypotenuses to have a length of 1 if you want to. In fact, you can start by drawing a circle with radius 1 and centre O, and put a point P on your circle, and then add two points B and E on the circle such that $\widehat{POB} = \theta$ and $\widehat{POE} = \psi$. Then add two points C and F on segment $[OP]$ such that $\widehat{OCB}$ and $\widehat{OFE}$ are right angles

Comment: @Stef Oh I can then? It makes sense a bit after thinking about that. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Stef I did what you suggested but got a bit confused on how to show that $BC > FE$? Can you clarify more on that?

Comment: I'd choose $AC=DF=a$: starting from $p>q$ it is easy to show that $${p\over\sqrt{a^2+p^2}}>{q\over\sqrt{a^2+q^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider $\triangle{ABC}$ such that $\angle{ABC}=\psi$ and $\angle{ACB}=\theta$.

Let $D$ be a point on $BC$ such that $AD\perp BC$.

We use the following claim. A proof of the claim is written at the end of this answer.

**Claim** : In $\triangle{ABC}$, if $\angle{ACB}\gt \angle{ABC}$, then $AB\gt AC$.

Using the claim above, we have
$$\begin{align}\theta\gt \psi&\implies AB\gt AC
\\\\&\implies \frac{AD}{AC}\gt\frac{AD}{AB}
\\\\&\implies \sin\theta\gt\sin\psi.\ \blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

In the following, let us prove the following claim :

**Claim** : In $\triangle{ABC}$, if $\angle{ACB}\gt \angle{ABC}$, then $AB\gt AC$.

*Proof* :

Suppose that $AB=AC$. Then, $\angle{ABC}=\angle{ACB}$. This is a contradiction.

Suppose that $AB\lt AC$. Taking a point $E$ on $AC$ such that $AB=AE$, we have $\angle{ACB}\lt \angle{AEB}=\angle{ABE}\lt\angle{ABC}$. This is a contradiction.$\ \square$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a circle of radius $1$ centered at the point $O$. Fix any point $A$ on the circle. Fix a point $B$ on the circle such that $\angle BOA=\frac{\pi}2-\psi$. Let $BB'$ be the altitude of the triangle $BOA$.  Draw a radius $r$ from the point $O$ inside the angle $BOA$ such that the angle between $r$ and $OA$ is $\frac{\pi}2-\theta$. Then the ray $r$ ends and the point $C$ at the circle, which is contained
in the arc $AB$, because $\theta>\psi$ . Let $CC'$ be the altitude of the triangle $COA$. Then $C'$ belongs to the segment $B'A$. Since $C\ne B$, we have $C'\ne B'$, so
$$\sin\theta=|OC'|=|OB'|+|B'C'|=\sin\psi+|B'C'|>\sin\psi.$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used your image with some modifications: Let $AC=DF=1$ and $AB=H$.
[image]
Since $\theta>\psi$ we have $p>q.$ But then
$$p^2>q^2$$
$$p^2+p^2q^2>q^2+p^2q^2$$ $$p^2(1+q^2)>q^2(1+p^2)$$
and
$$\frac p{\sqrt{1+p^2}}>\frac{q}{\sqrt{1+q^2}}$$
that is
$$\sin\theta=\frac pH>\frac qh=\sin\psi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I show the result is true even if neither the hypotenuses or the adjacent sides are not necessarily equal.

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be the sides adjacent to $\theta$ and $\psi$ respectively.
Let $h_1$ and $h_2$ be the hypotenuses for $\theta$ and $\psi$ respectively.

Let $p = q*x \ $ where $x>1$.
Let $a_1 = a_2*y \ $ where $0 < y < x$.

This range of $y$  is based on the fact that for a right angle triangle, if $\theta > \psi$ then $p/a_1 > q/a_2 \rightarrow  a_1 < a_2 x. \ $ (If $a_1 < a_2 x$ and $a_1 = a_2 y \ $ then $y < x$). This is related to the fundamental idea that the largest angle is opposite the largest side.

Let's assume to the contrary that $\sin \theta \leq \sin \ \psi$ when p>q and $\theta > \psi$ and see if this leads to a contradiction.

If $\sin \theta \leq \sin \psi$ then by definition $\frac{p}{h_1} \leq \frac{q}{h_2}$

Using Pythagorus theorem,

$\frac p {\sqrt{a_1^2 +p^2}} \leq \frac q {\sqrt{a_2^2 +q^2}}$

Putting everything in terms of q and $a_2$ we get:
$\frac {q x} {\sqrt{a_2^2 y^2 +q^2 x^2}} \leq \frac q {\sqrt{a_2^2 +q^2}}$
$\frac {q^2 x^2} {(a_2^2 y^2 +q^2 x^2)} \leq \frac {q^2} {(a_2^2 +q^2)}$

$x^2 (a_2^2 +q^2)  \leq (a_2^2 y^2 +q^2 x^2)$
$x^2 a_2^2 + x^2 q^2  \leq a_2^2 y^2 + q^2x^2$
$x^2 a_2^2 \leq a_2^2 y^2 $
$x^2 \leq y^2 $

which contradicts the initial assumption that y<x (if x and y are positive non zero numbers).